# UserWarning from Python pandas about reindexed Boolean Series key

Tags: python, pandas

When I use indexes to visit a pandas.DataFrame, it gave a userswarnings and they didn't interfere its output. I expect to know how did this userwarning happen and what should I do to avoid these userwarning? Thanks for everyone's attention.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[k, ass4Dict[k], k[:2], k[-2:]] for k in ass4Dict])
df.columns = ['string', 'count', 'lstr', 'rstr']
df = df[df['count'] >= 10]
**df = df[df['lstr'].map(lambda x:x in gram2Dict)][df['rstr'].map(lambda x:x in gram2Dict)]**
df['lstrCNT'] = df['lstr'].map(lambda x: float(gram2Dict[x]))
df['rstrCNT'] = df['rstr'].map(lambda x: float(gram2Dict[x]))
df['conPow'] = df['lstrCNT'] * df['rstrCNT']
df['lstrPow'] = df['count'] / df['lstrCNT']
df['rstrPow'] = df['count'] / df['rstrCNT']
df['aux4Ratio'] = df['count'] / df['conPow']
df['aux4Log'] = df['aux4Ratio'].map(lambda x: -log(x))
**df = df[df['aux4Log'] < 11][df['lstrPow'] >= 0.5][df['rstrPow'] >= 0.5]**
```

....

沈钦言 359

纪小蕊 158

顾持钧 949

林晋修 642

4

0.256721019745 1.22976207733

ch_extract.py:153: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  df = df[df['lstr'].map(lambda x:x in gram2Dict)][df['rstr'].map(lambda x:x in gram2Dict)]
ch_extract.py:161: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  df = df[df['aux4Log'] < 11][df['lstrPow'] >= 0.5][df['rstrPow'] >= 0.5]

Answer (score 2):

If we just take the last line and recreate it as the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(50, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df[df.A < 11][df.B >= 25][df.C >= 25]
```

The final line is stringing together a series of slices. After the first slice, each subsequent slice needs to be reindexed as the resulting data frame does not contain all the items in the previous slice.

In this case, the proper form would be to combine your boolean slice into one expression:

```
df[(df.A < 11) & (df.B >= 25) & (df.C >= 25)]
```

Some other cases that might cause this warning would be as follows:

```
df[df.sort_values(['A'], ascending=[False]).duplicated(subset='B', keep='first')]
```

In which case, use the loc command:

```
df.loc[df.sort_values(['A'], ascending=[False]).duplicated(subset='B', keep='first')]
```